# How can you retry after an exception in Javascript when using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, promise, bluebird

I'm using the Bluebird promise library. I have a chain of promisified functions like the following:

```
    receiveMessageAsync(params)
    .then(function(data)) {
        return [data, handleMessageAsync(request)];
    })
    .spread(function(data, response) {
        return [response, deleteMessageAsync(request)];
    })
    .spread(function(response, data) {
        return sendResponseAsync(response);
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        return waitForMessage(data);
    })
    .catch (function(err) {
       // handle error here
    });
```

Occasionally sendMessage will fail because, let's say, the server to respond to isn't available. I want the code to keep on trying to respond forever until it succeeds. You can't simply wrap the sendMessage in a catch because it doesn't actually throw an exception, I suppose, it calls the "error" function which, in this promisified code is the "catch" at the bottom. So there must be some way to "retry" send message in the "catch" section. The problem is that even if I retry in a loop in the "catch" I still have no way to jump up to the promise chain and execute the remaining promisified functions. How do I deal with this?

EDIT:

My retry for a HTTP post ended up looking like this:

```
function retry(func) {
    return func()
        .spread(function(httpResponse) {
            if (httpResponse.statusCode != 200) {
                Log.error("HTTP post returned error status: "+httpResponse.statusCode);
                Sleep.sleep(5);
                return retry(func);
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            Log.err("Unable to send response via HTTP");
            Sleep.sleep(5);
            return retry(func);
        });
}
```

Comment: I see no `sendMessage` here.

Comment: Sorry, sendResponse should be sendMessage

Comment: I think its interesting that I said I want to retry forever but every answer so far has been written for only a finite number of retries. There must be something about looping forever that bothers people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a sample retry function (not yet tested):

```
function retry(maxRetries, fn) {
  return fn().catch(function(err) { 
    if (maxRetries <= 0) {
      throw err;
    }
    return retry(maxRetries - 1, fn); 
  });
}
```

The idea is that you can wrap a function that returns a promise with something that will catch and retry on error until running out of retries. So if you're going to retry `sendResponseAsync`:

```
receiveMessageAsync(params)
.then(function(data)) {
    return [data, handleMessageAsync(request)];
})
.spread(function(data, response) {
    return [response, deleteMessageAsync(request)];
})
.spread(function(response, data) {
    return retry(3, function () { return sendResponseAsync(response); });
})
.then(function(data) {
    return waitForMessage(data);
})
.catch (function(err) {
   // handle error here
});
```

Since the `retry` promise won't actually throw until all retries have been exhausted, your call chain can continue.

**Edit**:

Of course, you could always loop forever if you preferred:

```
function retryForever(fn) {
  return fn().catch(function(err) { 
    return retryForever(fn); 
  });
}
```

Comment: `return retry(3, function () { return sendResponseAsync(response); });` can be `return retry(3, sendResponseAsync.bind(null, response));`

Comment: Yep, as long as you're not using ancient JS.

Comment: Please explain what the .bind(null, response) does and how it works. I've used bind before, but only in the sense of .bind(this) so that I can access my object's scope within the promise chain.

Comment: Great answer but I have one more problem. This functions are all methods on the current object so in the beginning I bind "this". So the begninng really looks like "receiveMessageAsync(params).bind(this)" and then later I call "this.sendMessageAsync". When I wrap it within the "retry" function, I no long have access to "this". How can I bind it again?

Comment: Using .bind(null, param1, param2, ...) fixed my problem above but I have no idea why

Comment: `.bind` on a function creates a new version of the function where you can change what `this` points to and populate its parameters (known as currying). `.bind(x)` within Bluebird promises is basically like doing an automatic `.bind(x)` on each callback.

If you want to set `this` for the function that `retryForever` calls, you can `bind` it, like `return retryForever(this.sendMessageAsync.bind(this, response));`

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was regarding the multiple parameters passed to bind. I didn't realize that the additional parameters were passed to the function. And also the meaning of the "null". I guess my bind will work with either this or null since that function does not require the score to be set.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small helper that acts like `then` but retries the function.

```
Promise.prototype.retry = function retry(onFulfilled, onRejected, n){
    n = n || 3; // default to 3 retries
    return this.then(function(result) {
         return Promise.try(function(){ 
             return onFulfilled(result); // guard against synchronous errors too
         }).catch(function(err){
             if(n <= 0) throw err;
             return this.retry(onFulfilled, onRejected, n - 1);
         }.bind(this)); // keep `this` value
    }.bind(this), onRejected);
};
```

Which would let you write your code prettier like:

```
receiveMessageAsync(params)
.then(function(data)) {
    return [data, handleMessageAsync(request)];
})
.spread(function(data, response) {
    return [response, deleteMessageAsync(request)];
})
.retry(function(response, data) {
    return sendResponseAsync(response); // will retry this 3 times
})
.then(function(data) {
    return waitForMessage(data);
})
.catch (function(err) {
   // I don't like catch alls :/ Consider using `.error` instead.
});
```

Comment: please don't extend natives... or if you do, at least check: `if( !Promise.prototype.retry ){`

Answer (score 1):

I just released https://github.com/zyklus/promise-repeat, which retries a promise until it either times out or a maximum number of attempts are hit.  It allows you to write:

```
receiveMessageAsync(params)
...
.spread(retry(
    function(response, data) {
        return sendResponseAsync(response);
    }
))
...
```