# Handling promise rejections outside the promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, dom-events, es6-promise

I'm familiar with how promises work and what an unhandled promise rejection is, however I have one case that I'm having difficulty identifying exactly how to catch this particular unhandled promise rejection error.

My goal is to create a rate limited retry handler that can sit inline with a series of sequential promise functions.

I'm using a limiter class that implements a transform stream. Messages going into the stream are only emitted at the rate limited rate, which is used to enforce the retry rate.

My retry handler implements a function `sendMessage` that returns a promise with the result. If the message fails to send the retry handler should retry sending the message up to the specified maximum number of retries. It should also limit the outgoing messages to the specified rate.

The retry handler doesn't actually make the API request itself, that is done by the registered API handler function (which is a 3rd party library that abstracts the actual API calls). The API can fail in one of two ways:

1. the call fails directly and the promise from the handler gets rejected and gets caught in the .catch of the `sendMessage` function

or

2. the API handler doesn't fail but the result back from the handler is null, in which case the `errorEmitter` module at some later point emits an event (the `errorEmitter` module extends `EventEmitter`).

```
class RetryMessageHandler extends Readable {

  constructor(msg, limit, interval, max, handler, errorEmitter) {
    super({objectMode: true});
    this._limiter = new RateLimiter(limit, interval);
    this._retryCount = 0;
    this._maxRetries = max;
    this._msg = msg;
    this._handler = handler;
    this._errorEmitter = errorEmitter;

    // The retry handler is intended as single use. The promise is
    // created and stored to deal with the 2 different rejection 
    // scenarios

    this._promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      this._resolve = resolve; 
      this._reject = reject;
    });

    this.retryTrigger = this.retryTrigger.bind(this);
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);

    // catch the messages as they exit the rate limiter
    this._limiter.on('data', this.sendOrder);

    // add the listener for the message failed event
    this._errorEmitter.prependOnceListener('Sending Message Failed', this.retryTrigger);

    // allows send() to push messages into the rate limiter
    this.pipe(this._limiter);
  }

  // after instantiation of the retry handler this method is
  // called to send the message with retries
  sendMessage() {
    this._retryCount++;

    // attempt to send message via API message handler
    this._handler(this._msg)

      .then((result) => {

        // check if the result received was null
        if (result) {
          
          // remove the errorEmitter module listener
          this._errorEmitter.removeListener('Sending Message Failed', this.retryTrigger);

          // resolve the retry handler promise and return the 
          // result to the retry handler caller.
          this._resolve(result);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        
        // scenario 1: Message sending failed directly
        // Need to remove the errorEmitter to avoid triggering twice
        this._errorEmitter.removeListener('Sending Message Failed', this.retryTrigger);

        // Trigger the retry method
        this.send();
      })

    return this._promise;
  }

  // required function due to extending Readable
  _read(size: number) {
    /* no op */
  }

  // Scenario 2: Message sending failed indirectly.
  // This method that is called whenever the errorEmitter module
  // emits a 'Sending Message Failed' event
  retryTrigger(err) {
    // Trigger the retry method
    this.send();
  }

  // Handles the retry sending the message
  send() {

    // Check if we've already exceed the maximum number of retries
    if (this._retryCount >= this._maxRetries) {
      this._errorEmitter.removeListener('Sending Message Failed', this.retryTrigger);


      // THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS
      // We need to throw an error because we've exceeded the max
      // number of retries. This error causes the unhandled promise rejection error
      throw new ExceededRetryCountError('Exceeded maximum number of retries', this._msg);
    }

    // if can retry we need to reset the errorEmitter listener
    this._errorEmitter.prependOnceListener('Sending Message Failed', this.retryTrigger);

    // Finally push the message into the rate limiter.
    // The message will come out the other side and call the
    // sendMessage() method and the whole thing starts over again
    this.push(this._msg);
  } 
}
```

Originally, instead of throwing the error I was using `this._reject(new ExceededRetryCountError('Exceeded maximum number of retries', this._msg));` but this still had the same issue.

I found this related question ([How can you retry after an exception in Javascript when using promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471131/how-can-you-retry-after-an-exception-in-javascript-when-using-promises)) but this only deals with the retry case when failures occur inside the promise chain.

Comment: `sendMessage` returns `this._promise` so I assume the caller catches a rejection somewhere in the event queue and not in the same call stack, maybe you can try `this._promise.catch(ignore=>ignore)` after `this._promise = new Promise...`

Comment: Thanks, the code calling this sendMessage function does have a .catch after this function i.e. sendMessage().then().catch(err)

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the issue causing the unhandled exception. When a function that returns a promise, throws an error the catch statement is executed on the same tick. If the error throws on the same tick as the function is executed then the catch handler must already be assigned. This is usually done by calling `function().then( … ).catch(err)` , however with promises its also usually ok to deal directly with the returned promise by `let promise = function(); promise.then( ... ).catch(err)`. In the second case though that will cause an unhandled exception because at the time the error is thrown the catch statement hasn’t yet been assigned to the promise. After attaching the catch statement it will actually catch the error correctly but the unhandled rejection warning has already triggered.